# Claims from Azure B2C and ADFS as an Identity Provider

Tags: azure, openid, adfs, azure-ad-b2c

I'm using ADFS as an IdP for Azure B2C through OpenID Connect. Login works, but I do not receive any claims from ADFS.
Here is a part of TrusFrameworkExtensions policy:

```
<OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="socialIdpUserId" PartnerClaimType="UPN" />
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" PartnerClaimType="tid" />
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="Name" />
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" PartnerClaimType="family_name" />
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="name" />
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="contosoAuthentication" />
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="OpenIDADFS" />
        </OutputClaims>
```

And here is the example of JWT token i receive:

```
{
"exp": 1536674800,
  "nbf": 1536671200,
  "ver": "1.0",
  "iss": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/2263fb1b-1249-4245-a174-cb9d518d7ce3/v2.0/",
  "sub": "f5fa8b7b-5e14-4b49-8f9f-33ea5c8b2149",
 "aud": "21d60a4b-6e33-4e22-b618-586882744560",
 "acr": "b2c_1a_signuporsigninfmdclient",
 "nonce": "defaultNonce",
 "iat": 1536671200,
 "auth_time": 1536671200,
 "idp": "OpenIDADFS",
 "name": "unknown"
}
```

No claims in here. 
Here is my ADFS setup with claims from AD
[image]

The relying party policy SignUpOgSignIn

```
  <RelyingParty>
<DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUpOrSignInFmdClient" />
<TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
  <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub"/>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

How to receive claims?

Comment: What claims is ADFS outputting? Can you show the ADFS claim rules?

Comment: OK, So your outputting "UPN" from ADFS and receiving it as "socialIdpUserId" in B2C. Are you then outputting socialIdpUserId in your Relying Party policy?

Comment: Not sure what is my Relying Party policy? On ADFS? There is no relying party trust to B2C here. B2C is registered as an application on ADFS. I used this instruction: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuredev/2017/06/23/using-adfs-as-an-identity-provider-for-azure-ad-b2c/ for setup

Comment: Relying Party Policy is the policy in B2C that you execute. e.g. SignupSignin

Comment: Aha. Posted in the question. Here are something that should match with claims from ADFS I think...

Comment: Add <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="socialIdpUserId" PartnerClaimType="UPN"  />

Comment: Yes! It works now! Thank you. Is it anyhow possible to add group claims from ADFS to the B2C generated token? Security group membership is send as claim to B2C, but how to make B2C to add it to token?

Comment: Sure - Output in claim rule from ADFS. Accept Group claim in ADFS technical Profile in B2C (need to add a new claim type). Output in relying party claims.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else dealing with the same issue or similar issues, the necessary piece was to add `<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="socialIdpUserId" PartnerClaimType="UPN" />`

(per Jamie's comment)

For reference, the B2C custom policy Azure Sample is very helpful. https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/master/SocialAccounts/TrustFrameworkBase.xml